# Filling a pointer with a different method

Tags: c++, pointers

The following situation:

```
class Main{
   void MainMethod(){
      C * c;
      B * b = new B();
      b->fillC(c);
   }
};

class B{
   void fillC(C* c){
      c = new C();
   }
};

class C{
};
```

In my software I have this situation. At the end of the program c is still empty for class Main. Why is this?

Comment: the c=new C -assignment does not do anything. Use a reference to pointer.

Comment: @tp1: It absolutely does something. It just doesn't do what the OP thinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer `c` is copied into the `fillC` function - this is known as *passing by value*. You then assign to that copy. The original `c` variable from `MainMethod` is left unaffected. You need to pass the pointer *by reference* if you want to change it:

```
class B{
  void fillC(C*& c){
    c = new C();
  }
};
```

Now the `c` inside `fillC` refers to the same pointer as the `c` in `MainMethod`. Changing the value of one affects the value of the other.

You could alternatively change the parameter of `fillC` to type `C**`, call it with `fillC(&c)` and assign to it with `*c = new C()` - but you're already using a mishmash of idioms from other languages, so I wouldn't recommend this.

Don't forget to do `delete c` at some point!

Comment: What do you mean by "but you're already using a mishmash of idioms from other languages". What things am I doing here that is not following "the rules" of c++?

Answer (score 0):

Change B::fillC to:

```
class B{
   void fillC(C*& c){
        c = new C();
    }
};
```